# How to make same-size cards that display varying amounts of text without overflow?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Currently I have a container that defines the boundary for a set of cards:

```
.cards-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 5px solid violet;
}
.card {
    margin: 10px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    width: 25em;
    /* height: 25em; */
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

In the react code I display them on the page like:

```
<div className={classes['cards-container']}>
    {
        articlesData.length > 0 ?
        articlesData.map( (article) => 
        <div key={article.id} className={classes.card}>
            <Card 
                itle={article.title}
                body={article.abstract}
                />
        </div>
        ) :
        null
    }
</div>
```

The `Card` component has the following css:

```
.mycard {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    /* box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.9); */
    border: 5px solid red;
}

.mycard-body {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.mycard-header {
    /* font-size: 1.5rem; */
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.mycard-footer {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

Finally, here's how the card is defined:

```
const Card = (props) => {
    
    const mainText = props.body.slice(0,300);

    const [textBody, setTextBody] = useState(mainText + '...');

    

    const onSeeMore = () => {
        setTextBody(props.body);
    }

    return <>
        <div className={classes.mycard}>
            <div className={classes['mycard-header']}>
                {props.title}
            </div>
            <div className={classes['mycard-body']}>
                {textBody}
            </div>
            <div className={classes['mycard-footer']}>
                <button type='button' onClick={onSeeMore}>See More.</button>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </>
};
```

The text that populates these cards on the main page is dynamic, so sometimes the full box assigned to a card doesn't filled and looks like the following:
[image]

I need the bounding blax box because I have blurring and other transitions when hovering on a card. How can I make it so that the cards are the same size but with varying amounts of content?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Apply your transitions, `background-color: white`, etc. to the `.card` elements, not to the `.mycard`. They will be the same height.

Example: https://codepen.io/zkla/pen/vYaymWo

Comment: Yea I can see how that would fix things but I also want the text to fill more, then I'd have less white space. ANy chance I can do that?

Comment: Output more text? You are trimming it at 300 symbols.

Comment: That was my temporary solution -- I should have removed it. Found a solution anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone else will have this issue but I found a solution:

From the parent class, I know pass the background color of the card with prop `color`. And in the `Card` component I overwrite the styling, see below:
In parent class,

```
const cardColor = 'white'
<Card 
   title={article.title}
   body={article.abstract}
   color={cardColor} 
/>
```

In Card.js:

```
<div className={classes.mycard} style={{'backgroundColor': props.color}}>
```

I constrained the text in the header and body ('mycard-header','mycard-body') to some `n` number of lines via the below CSS:

```
.mycard-header {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.2rem;

    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
}

.mycard-body {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 7;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

    display: -webkit-box;
}
```